# Error xsl during installation propel_generator by pear

Tags: php, xslt, wamp, pear, propel

I'm in the install Propel 1.7.0 via pear in wamp. Currently have:

```
PHP v. 5.4.16
- libxslt v. 1.1.27
- libxml v. 2.7.8
- libxml2 v. 2.7.6

Apache v. 2.4.4

Mysql v. 5.6.12

Log v. 1.12.7

Phing v. 2.7.0
```

When you try to install propel_generator:

```
pear channel-discover pear.propelorm.org
pear install propel/propel_generator
```

I get error:

```
propel/propel_generator requires PHP extension "xsl"
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Someone tell me why? In phpinfo see active modulus xsl.

Comment: Just wild guessing here: You are using the pear.bat from a command shell? Maybe the cli build of php on your machine uses a diffrent php.ini than the php-apache module, one that doesn't load the xsl extension. Try `php -r "echo extension_loaded('xsl')?'yes':'no';"` exactly where you would type the pear command to test that.

Comment: actually after the query received "no". php and pear I use from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\ . How can I set the download of the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue after adding the extension was the pear cache. After clearing it everything worked like a charm!